# Open browser using intent with URL ending .jhtml force close

Tags: android, android-intent

I've been getting force closes opening url's that end in .jhtml
Example URL:
http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1691428/beck-hansens-song-reader-sheet-music-album.jhtml

The Error:
0android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=

I can't figure out a decent workaround.
Any suggestions?

Cheers,
Zed

-edit-
Here's the code:

```
getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

Comment: Have you given the internet permission? And, post the code which you're trying to open browser?

Comment: It's added. I used the constructor instead of the setData method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine on my emulator using through this code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String url = "http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1691428/beck-hansens-song-reader-sheet-music-album.jhtml";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Have a screenshot -

[image: Screenshot]

And, don't forget to include the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Try above steps.

Comment: Interesting. Do you think it's because I used the constructor instead of the setData method?

Comment: Yeah. I can't replicate with either method though. We caught it in bugsense. :/

Comment: I've accepted the answer since I changed it to use setData. I don't see any other issues that could have caused it.

Comment: @ZedScio Did you try to start give like `this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));` instead of `this` just try with your `activityname.this` also

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1691428/beck-hansens-song-reader-sheet-music-album.jhtml");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

hope help